# swig: how to ignore unnamed struct

Tags: swig

I'm trying to swig third party code (i.e. I cannot modify that code). In one of the header files I'm including there is an unnamed struct inside a union as follows:

```
struct ThirdPartyStruct {
    union {
        uint8_t         rsvd499[8];
        struct {
            uint16_t    aaa;
            uint16_t    bbb;
            uint32_t    ccc;
        } inner_struct;
    };
};
```

This causes the following warning:

```
Warning 503: Can't wrap class $unnamed2$ unless renamed to a valid identifier.
```

Before including the header file, I tell swig to ignore all structs and unions (as shown below), but that  doesn't stop the warning.

```
%rename($ignore, %$isclass) "";     // ignore all classes/structs
%rename($ignore, %$isunion) "";     // ignore all unions

%include "third_party.h"
```

I know that it's just a warning and I could ignore it, but we have this rule that "there shall be no errors or warnings in the code". So, I'm just trying to find a way to suppress it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to suppress the warning is to suppress it for the whole file via:

- `-w503` on the SWIG command line.
- `#pragma SWIG nowarn=503` in the `.i` file.

  - Or symbolically: `#pragma SWIG nowarn=SWIGWARN_LANG_IDENTIFIER`
    Symbols are defined in `Lib\swigwarn.swg`.

Ref: [18.2 Warning message suppression](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Warnings_suppression)